# Memory corruption in f90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, memory-corruption

I have the following code.

```
      PROGRAM CTS
        implicit none
!C     driver for routine fourn
      INTEGER NDAT,NDIM
      PARAMETER(NDIM=1,NDAT=1024)
      INTEGER i,idum,isign,j,k,l,nn(NDIM)
      REAL data1(NDAT),data2(NDAT),ran1 ,x,dx 
      REAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE::F,F1


    allocate(F(NDAT),F1(NDAT))
    x=1.
    dx = (200.-1.)/real(NDAT)
   nn(1)=NDAT
    do i=1,NDAT
    F1(i) =atan(x-100)
    x= x + dx
   enddo
x=1.


    x=1. 
  isign=1
      call fo(F1,nn,1,isign)

  open(1,file="zresult.dat",status="replace")
 do i=1,NDAT
 write(1,*)x,F1(i)*dx
x= x + dx
enddo 


stop


       END
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      SUBROUTINE fo(data,nn,ndim,isign)
      INTEGER isign,ndim,nn(ndim)
      REAL data(*)
      INTEGER i1,i2,i2rev,i3,i3rev,ibit,idim,ifp1,ifp2,ip1,ip2,ip3,k1,&
      k2,n,nprev,nrem,ntot
      REAL tempi,tempr
      DOUBLE PRECISION theta,wi,wpi,wpr,wr,wtemp
      ntot=1
      do 11 idim=1,ndim
        ntot=ntot*nn(idim)
11    continue
      nprev=1
      do 18 idim=1,ndim
        n=nn(idim)
        nrem=ntot/(n*nprev)
        ip1=2*nprev
        ip2=ip1*n
        ip3=ip2*nrem
        i2rev=1
        do 14 i2=1,ip2,ip1
          if(i2.lt.i2rev)then
            do 13 i1=i2,i2+ip1-2,2
              do 12 i3=i1,ip3,ip2
                i3rev=i2rev+i3-i2
                tempr=data(i3)
                tempi=data(i3+1)
                data(i3)=data(i3rev)
                data(i3+1)=data(i3rev+1)
                data(i3rev)=tempr
                data(i3rev+1)=tempi
12            continue
13          continue
          endif
          ibit=ip2/2
1         if ((ibit.ge.ip1).and.(i2rev.gt.ibit)) then
            i2rev=i2rev-ibit
            ibit=ibit/2
          goto 1
          endif
          i2rev=i2rev+ibit
14      continue
        ifp1=ip1
2       if(ifp1.lt.ip2)then
          ifp2=2*ifp1
          theta=isign*6.28318530717959d0/(ifp2/ip1)
          wpr=-2.d0*sin(0.5d0*theta)**2
          wpi=sin(theta)
          wr=1.d0
          wi=0.d0
          do 17 i3=1,ifp1,ip1
            do 16 i1=i3,i3+ip1-2,2
              do 15 i2=i1,ip3,ifp2
                k1=i2
                k2=k1+ifp1
                tempr=sngl(wr)*data(k2)-sngl(wi)*data(k2+1)
                tempi=sngl(wr)*data(k2+1)+sngl(wi)*data(k2)
                data(k2)=data(k1)-tempr
                data(k2+1)=data(k1+1)-tempi
                data(k1)=data(k1)+tempr
                data(k1+1)=data(k1+1)+tempi
15            continue
16          continue
            wtemp=wr
            wr=wr*wpr-wi*wpi+wr
            wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi
17        continue
          ifp1=ifp2
        goto 2
        endif
        nprev=n*nprev
18    continue
      return
      END
!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The problem is  If I do not allocate `F1` and put `REAL F1(NDAT)`, the code runs without any problem, but when I allocate `F1` I will get the following error
I have tried all possibilities to understand what is happening `-fcheck=all` etc. it seems memory corruption.

```
*** Error in `./out': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x088a7f20 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0xB76BE133
#1  0xB76BE7D0
#2  0xB77C73FF
#3  0xB77C7424
#4  0xB74E4686
#5  0xB74E7AB2
#6  0xB751EFD2
#7  0xB75294C9
#8  0xB752A13C
#9  0xB7777607
#10  0xB776EECF
#11  0xB776EFB9
#12  0xB76BDA93
#13  0xB77D733B
#14  0xB74E9230
#15  0xB74E928C
#16  0xB76C09E7
#17  0x80496D4 in cts at z2.f90:33
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could you please help me to find out where the problem is.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please use some better formatting of your code when other people are supposed to understand it. Your indentation is horrible and completely inconsistent. I am sure it can be made much shorter (see [mcve]).

Comment: @ High Performance Mark could you please explain more how to use stat?

Comment: `allocate(..., stat=integer_variable)`, but it will not help you here. The error does not happen due to the allocate and does not happen during the allocate. See the answer.

Comment: Q Vladimir F  But why it does not happen when In the main I put F(NDAT), and only if I allocate F1 it happens???

Comment: It happens always, see below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `END` after the subroutine, put `CONTAINS` before the subroutine to make it *internal* the program, change assumed size array

```
data(*)
```

to assumed shape array

```
data(:)
```

(just using `data(NDAT)` would also help)

then you can compile your code as

```
gfortran-7 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -fcheck=all memcorr.f90
```

and get clear message

```
> ./a.out 
At line 63 of file memcorr.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '1025' of dimension 1 of array 'data' above upper bound of 1024
```

## That means your are accessing your array out of bounds.

Line 63 is:

```
 data(i3)=data(i3rev)
```

so `i3` or `i3rev` is too large (larger than `NDAT`). You must find out why and fix that.

---

The point is: **use explicit interfaces**, assumed shape arrays and all other Fortran 90 stuff that will help you find bugs.

The best thing is to **use modules** for all your subroutines and functions.

Comment: But why it does not happen when In the  main I put F(NDAT), and only if I allocate F1 it happens???

Comment: You bug happens **ALWAYS**. You just don't notice sometimes. Buggy program is undefined. It can do anything at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: In this case it depends on the details how the operating systems allocates memory and where does it stores its information. It's not worth digging the details now, it is too complicated for your level. Just remember that memory corruption causes unpredictable bugs that can change at random.

Comment: Then if I send pointer to subroutine the problem should be solved?

Comment: What? Which pointer? Why? The error is the **out of bounds access**. You must fix your loops! Please do read error messages.